# Using SASS and CSS calc() within an animation delay

Tags: css, animation, sass, calc

I'm attempting to calculate (using CSS `calc()`) within an animation delay using SASS but it doesn't seem to output the result of the calculation (and rather just the calculation itself).

```
.home-slider-container .home-slider .each-slide svg .letter {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: svgAnimate 4s linear;
}

@for $i from 1 through 8 {
    .home-slider-container .home-slider .each-slide svg .letter-#{$i} {
        $test: calc(#{$i} / 2);
        animation-delay: #{$test};

    }
}
```

Any thoughts where I am going wrong?

Comment: Try `$test: $i / 2;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `calc()` is not sass function. It's just [css function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), like `rgba()`, for example. The result of calc is made on runtime/client side. If you want to calculate this on sass level, just write expression like `$i / 2` and final css will have calculated values. Here, I found it in sass reference for you: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#number_operations

To answer your question: `animation-delay: $i / 2;` in your for-loop will be just fine.